# how to initailize vuex state with initialState which has default value?

Tags: state, vuex

Tried to initalize vuex state (some modules and json data) with `initialState` which I defined has default value when logging out. 
But initialState has changed value when calling reset(state) mutation.

Uses:
axio interceptors,
vue-router

I tried to JSON.parse, Object.assign, etc. but not working.

index.js (store)

```
const initialState = {
  plan: plan.state, // module
  loggedIn: false,
  errorFlg: false,
  message: {
    error: null,
    warn: null,
    auth: null
  }
}

export default new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    plan,
    xxx,
    xxx
  },

  // state: initialState,
  state: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(initialState)),

  mutations: {
    reset(state) {
      console.log(initialState) // initialState has changed value
      Object.keys(state).forEach(key => {
        if (state[key] !== null && state[key] !== undefined) {
          if (state[key] instanceof Object) {
            Object.assign(state[key], initialState[key])
          } else {
            state[key] = initialState[key]
          }
        }
      })
    },
```

plan.js (store)

```
export default {
  state: {
    selectedBuildingType: null,
    selectedCategory: null,
    selectedMaker: null,
    selectedPackType: null,
    startDate: new Date().toISOString().substr(0, 10),
    endDate: null,
    flyerPostQuoteNumber: "",
    packagePlanName: ""
  },

  mutations: {
    updatePlanSelectedBuildingType(state, payload) {
      state.selectedBuildingType = payload;
    },
    updatePlanSelectedCategory(state, payload) {
      state.selectedCategory = payload;
    },
    updatePlanSelectedMaker(state, payload) {
      state.selectedMaker = payload;
    },
    updatePlanSelectedPackType(state, payload) {
      state.selectedPackType = payload;
    },
    updatePlanStartDate(state, payload) {
      state.startDate = payload;
    },
    updatePlanEndDate(state, payload) {
      state.endDate = payload;
    },
    updateFlyerPostQuoteNumber(state, payload) {
      state.flyerPostQuoteNumber = payload;
    },
    updatePackagePlanName(state, payload) {
      state.packagePlanName = payload;
    }
  }
};
```

Header.vue

```
logout() {
      cookieJs.delCookie("access_token", "/");
      cookieJs.delCookie("uid", "/");
      cookieJs.delCookie("client", "/");
      delete sessionStorage.accountInfo;
      indexStore.commit("reset");
      indexStore.commit("loggedIn", false);
      window.location.reload(); // it doesn't work either.
      this.$router.push({ name: "login" });
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried changing `plan: plan.state` to `plan:  Object.assign({}, plan.state)` while initializing initial state constant.

Comment: @MohsinMehmood I just tried and it works perfectly!!! Thank you very much!!! Could I ask you the flow of this?

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean by flow but when you had `plan: plan.state` it meant that plan property was holding a reference to the plan store state object. So any changes made to plan store state object were reflected by initialState plan property. So I suggested to change the plan: property to point to a copy of plan store state object

Comment: @MohsinMehmood Thank you for replying. It was so helpful!